# gtk.window()? Trouble with Matplotlib and/or PyGTK

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to learn more about matplotlib, using this tutorial:

http://matplotlib.org/users/navigation_toolbar.html

The section in question introduces something called PyGTK which I am
previously unfamilliar with. It is for making interactive controls for
your plot windows.

I try to run the example on the page:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import NavigationToolbar2GTKAgg as NavigationToolbar

win = gtk.window()
win.connect("destroy", lambda x: gtk.main_quit())
win.set_default_size(400,300)
win.set_title("Embedding in GTK")

vbox = gtk.VBox()
win.add(vbox)

fig = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1,2,3])

canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)  # a gtk.DrawingArea
vbox.pack_start(canvas)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar(canvas, win)
vbox.pack_start(toolbar, False, False)

win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

If i copythis to the interpreter nothing at all happens.
If I try to run it as a module it reaches the line

```
win = gtk.window()
```

where it stops due to "NameError: global name 'gtk' is not defined".

Where do I go from here? I have not been able to find any source
that explains this better.

Comment: Have you tried to `import gtk`? Do you have it installed?

Comment: Adding "import gtk" after the other import statements makes no difference. I have gtk installed.

Comment: You still get `NameError: global name 'gtk' is not defined` even when you `import gtk`? That seems unlikely.

Comment: No, I get "AttributeError:'module object has no attribute 'window'".

Comment: Well: 1. That's hardly *"no difference"*; and 2. `'window' != 'Window'`.

Comment: That is correct. While it said 'Window' in my post here, it always said 'window' in my actual code.